# PHP SoapClient - handle namespaces?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to consume SOAP web service which expects payload as follows:

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:quer="http://query.services.services.find/" xmlns:mod="http://model.query.services.test/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <quer:findRecords>
         <mod:queryParameters>
            <param1>test</msisdn>
         </mod:queryParameters>
      </quer:findRecords>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I have tried so far:

```
1)

$data = array('queryParameters' => array('param1' => 'test'));
$soapClient->findRecords($data);

2)

$param= array('param1' => 'test');
$queryParams= new SoapVar($data, SOAP_ENC_ARRAY, NULL, "http://model.query.services.test/", "queryParameters", "mod");
$soapClient->findRecords($queryParams);
```

This is the error i got:

> Type: SoapFault
>   Message: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"queryParameters"). Expected elements are <{http://model.query.services.test//}queryParameters>

How can I pass properly this "mod" namespace ?